# 'SiftFeatureDetector' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use SiftFeatureDetector but I'm having undeclared identifier error. But I imported the libraries:

```
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>

// ...

SiftFeatureDetector detector; detector.detect(timg, kps, mask);
SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor;
extractor.compute(timg, kps, desc);
```

Comment: @baci i used 2.4 version. thank you.

Comment: Isn't 2.4 rather old?